# inner product space questions

Tags: inner-products

I didn't succeed in solving these two short questions (in the link).

In the first one I think I need to work with bases, but I don't know how.
In the second question I just don't know how to start.

Can you show me how to solve these?

[image]

Comment: Work via the definitions and show the inclusions by showing $x \in A \implies x \in B$. How far does this get you?

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, prove that

$$(A+B)^\perp=A^\perp\cap B^\perp:$$

$$x\in (A+B)^\perp\implies \langle x,a+b\rangle=0\;,\;\;\forall\,a\in A\,,\,b\in B$$

Now, *choose* first $\;b=0\;$ and then $\;a=0\;$ in the above, getting

$$\begin{cases}\langle x,a\rangle=0\;,\;\;\forall a\in A\iff x\in A^\perp\\{}\\\langle x,b\rangle =0\;,\;\;\forall b\in B\iff x\in B^\perp\end{cases}\implies\;x\in A^\perp\cap B^\perp$$

I leave to you the second, opposite inclusion.

Finally, to obtain your first inclusion, put simply $\;W=A^\perp\;,\;\;U=B^\perp\;$  and pass to orthogonal complements.

**Added on request:**

$$\forall\,x=T^*v\in\text{Im}\,T\;,\;\;\forall\,u\in\ker T:$$

$$\langle u,x\rangle=\langle u,T^*v\rangle=\langle Tu,v\rangle=\langle0,v\rangle=0\implies u\in \left(\text{Im}\,T^*\right)^\perp$$

Comment: tnx!! got it now. do you know how to solve the second question? i tried to prove equality between the two sub-spaces by taking some vector v from the first and some vector u from the second, and showed that they are perpendicular. I don't know if that is good enough to prove that...

Comment: @John Take a peek at what I added to my answer.